# POWER BI Selected Value to Return Filtered Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that looks a little like this:

```
Product Version Unit 
p1  V1  10 
p2  V1  20 
p3  V2  50 
p4  V2  10 
p5  V3  5
p6  V4  20 
p7  V1  15 
p8  V2  15 
p9  V2  10 
p10 V3  5 
p11 V4  20 
p12 V4  10
p13 V3  5
```

I have a slicer that contains the different versions:

V1, V2, V3, V4

I would like to return the sum of the units based on the specific version selected in slicer.
I would also like to return the list of the units based on the specific version selected in slicer.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

I have tried setting up a table that contains the version, then using selected value function on this value but I cannot seem to find a way to return the sum of unit or the list of units based on the selection.

Comment: If you create a measure SUM([Units]) and put it in a card visual, and then you select a [Version] from the slicer, the only values that will show/be summarized those that meet the criteria you selected. if you wanted to *always* filter by some value, you could use CALCULATE()

Comment: If you drop a table visual onto the canvas and then add the columns you want to show from your table, you'll get all the records showing. Then if you add a slicer viz to your canvas and add the Version to the Field well, then you can choose which version you want to see, and it will filter your visual.

Comment: Hi, I got one question: for V2, there are two 10 in units. Do you want the list show only one 10 in units or two 10 in units? Or otherwise one 10 in units column and add another column show times as 2?

Comment: Hi, I basically want the measure to equal 35 as it will be all units that are in version v2. So if I wrote the measure for v2, it would show 35 if displayed in a card, and then different for each measure created. So I want to create a measure per version